# UISlider action - iOS

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, uislider

Hi, I am working in my first app. I want set action for each Slider values. For eg: slider value 3 and clicking the next button go to some view controller, if value 4 goes to some other controller.

```
- (IBAction)controlValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (self.sliders.value== 3) 
    {
        NSLog(@"value is 3");
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(90, 90, 35, 35);
        UILabel *label= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        label.text = @"Hi Man";
        [self.view addSubview:label];
    }
}
```

It's not working with above code. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check if `controlValueChanged:` is correctly invoked. Add something like `NSLog(@"value is %f", [sender value]);` in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of the sender

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
If (slider.value == 3)
```